# GetList возвращает 1 элемент

Tags: битрикс, api

```
   <?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
    CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_*");
$arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID' => 8);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
$arResult['PROP'] = $ob;
    }
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/log.txt', 
    (print_r($arResult['PROP'],true)));
    ?>
```

ShowCount до цикла 24

в цикле счетчик 24 раза срабатывает.

В полученном массиве только первый элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `GetNextElement` возвращает объект. Далее из этого объекта можно получить поля и свойства из инфоблока с помощью методов `GetFields` и `GetProperties`. Также вы в каждой итерации цикла перетираете данные, т.е. в один и тот же ключ добавляете новые данные.

```
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_*");
$arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID' => 8);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, array());
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){ // получаем объект
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();// получаем поля инфоблока итерации
    $arProp = $ob->GetProperties();// получаем свойства итерации
    // сохраняем данные в новый элемент массива []
    $arResult['PROP'][] = array(
        'FIELDS' => $arFields,
        'PROP' => $arProp,
    );
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($arResult['PROP'], true)."</pre>";
```

Если используете `GetNextElement`, то `$arSelect` не учитывается.
Такой вариант выборки очень не оптимальный, и если у вас много данных, выборка будет очень долгая. Лучший вариант – это сделать выборку через `Fetch` и указать только нужные поля и свойства в `$arSelect` к примеру:

```
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_TITLE", "PROPERTY_KEYWORDS"); // указываем все поля и свойства которые нам нужны PROPERTY_код свойства или id
$arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID' => 2);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($ar = $res->Fetch()){ // получаем сразу массив данных а не объект
    $arResult['PROP'][] = $ar; // сохраняем все в переменную в новый массив
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($arResult['PROP'], true)."</pre>";
```

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php)